# Removing a List Item from DynamoDb

Tags: javascript, amazon-dynamodb

Need to remove a list item from a DynamoDb database in a react app using its index.

Going by the example in
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.Js.03.html ,
**Update an Item (Conditionally)**

The update expression for removing an item is

```
UpdateExpression: "remove info.actors[0]",
```

What is the update expression when the index value is a parameter to the function?

Comment: If you just want to use the parameter instead of the hard coded zero, is there a reason you can't just build the string with the index? 

eg. "Remove info.actors[" + index + "]"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do this is to just build the `UpdateExpression` string with the appropriate number in it. As LazyElephant suggested in a comment: `"Remove info.actors[" + index + "]"`.

You might think that it should also be possible to write `remove info.actors[:i]` where `:i` is defined in `ExpressionAttributeValues`. But unfortunately, this doesn't work. DynamoDB refuses it as a syntax error. I can't say I understand why.